# can we limit git user for push or merge by git

Tags: git, svn, openssh, gitlab

I remember that when I was using SVN, I could able to define user and assign them different privileges without any third party application. I want to check do we have the same feature in Git?

If there isn't a similar future, what third-party application do you recommend? I review GitLab features, but I observe that in the free version 'Restrict push and merge access to certain users" is not available.

Initially I install Git and then OpenSSH but I couldn't figure it out how to restrict my users. I will appreciate if you have any best practice also share with me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Git commits and merges are client-side operations. You can restrict certain commits/merges from being pushed to the shared server, but you cannot restrict them from being *made* on the user's own machine.

To restrict what can be pushed where, use [hook scripts](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Customizing-Git-Git-Hooks) – specifically the `pre-receive` hook, which can check pushed commits and reject updates to the server-side branches.

However, these hook scripts must be written first, as there is no built-in "user account" tracking in Git; it relies on the system (e.g. SSH server or webserver) having already authenticated the user.

Generally the simplest option would be to use [Gitolite](https://gitolite.com/gitolite/index.html) which already has these hooks written, and provides a simpler [configuration language](https://gitolite.com/gitolite/conf.html) with access rules for branches, tags, users, etc.